# Induced representation of the symmetric group and tensor product of it

Tags: representation-theory, tensor-products

Given $n_1,n_2,n_3$ be positive integers,
let $V_1,V_2,V_3$ be representations of $S_{n_1}, S_{n_2}, S_{n_3}$, respectively.
Here, $S_n$ is the symmetric group on $n$ letters.

I wonder that
$$
(( V_1 \otimes V_2 ) \uparrow^{S_{n_1 + n_2}} \otimes V_3)\uparrow^{S_{n_1 + n_2 + n_3}} \; \cong \;( V_1 \otimes V_2 \otimes V_3)\uparrow^{S_{n_1 + n_2 + n_3}}\;.
$$

If it is false, then what is a counterexample?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is true.

More generally, let $G$ be a group, $H\times B\leq G$ a subgroup of $G$, $A\leq H$ a subgroup of $H$, $X$ a representation of $A$, and $Y$ a representation of $B$.

Then as representations of $H\times B$, 
$$X\uparrow^H_A\otimes Y\cong(X\otimes Y)\uparrow^{H\times B}_{A\times B}.$$

Taking $G=S_{n_1+n_2+n_3}$, $H=S_{n_1+n_2}$, $B=S_{n_3}$, $A=S_{n_1}\times S_{n_2}$, $X=V_1\otimes V_2$, $Y=V_3$, this gives
$$(V_1\otimes V_2)\uparrow^{S_{n_1+n_2}}_{S_{n_1}\times S_{n_2}}\otimes V_3
\cong (V_1\otimes V_2\otimes V_3)\uparrow^{S_{n_1+n_2}\times S_{n_3}}_{S_{n_1}\times S_{n_2}\times S_{n_3}}$$
as representations of $S_{n_1+n_2}\times S_{n_3}$, and then inducing to $S_{n_1+n_2+n_3}$ gives the isomorphism you want.